# Storing the result of a for loop as an array in c# and later get the sum of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, loops, sum

I have a for loop and want to save all of the results in an array, so that I could get the sum of all of the results. How can this be done? I am using Visual Studio Xamarin  (C#) to develop an Android app.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. Can't figure out the logic behind this.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *I have a for loop and want to save all of the results in an array*

Comment: I have a user input and when the button is clicked it will start looping the number until it reaches zero. For example if the input is 155, it calculates different sets (max 25 in each set). So there will be 7 sets: 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 5. I want to save all of these values and have hem shown in textViews in the app, but I also want to save them to make make further calculations (multiply every number by 5) and also save these values to get the sum of the multiplications. I hope you'll understand this.

Comment: I recommend you edit your question to include your above comment and also what these values are that are being saved, i.e., 7 sets of what?  The only input you mention in your example is '155'.  It seems that you are asking how to store a loop iterator into an array of size[25] arrays.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] results = new int[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    // calculation here 
    results[i] = resultOfCalculation;
}
int sum = results.Sum(); // LINQ method
```